# selecting nodes where all (dynamically created) items in a series match attributes

Tags: xpath, xquery

In the following XML (using Xquery):

```
let $xml :=

(<list xml:id="first">
  <item corresp="a"/>
</list>,
<list xml:id="second">
  <item corresp="a"/>
  <item corresp="b"/>
</list>,
<list xml:id="third">
  <item corresp="b"/>
</list>,
<list xml:id="third">
  <item corresp="c"/>
</list>,
<list xml:id="forth">
  <item corresp="b"/>
  <item corresp="c"/>
</list>)
```

I am trying to return `<list>` where `@corresp` has both `a` and `b` (this is a series that is dynamically constructed, from 1 - 15 items). However this:

```
return $xml[./item[@corresp=("a","b")]]
```

Returns

```
<list xml:id="first">
  <item corresp="a"/>
</list>
<list xml:id="second">
  <item corresp="a"/>
  <item corresp="b"/>
</list>
<list xml:id="third">
  <item corresp="b"/>
</list>
<list xml:id="forth">
  <item corresp="b"/>
  <item corresp="c"/>
</list>
```

When I am looking for this result

```
<list xml:id="second">
  <item corresp="a"/>
  <item corresp="b"/>
</list>
```

Additionally, the parameters contained in `("a","b")`are dynamically constructed. Therefore I am trying to identify a solution that can take any number/combination of parameters in a series, anywhere between 1 and 15.

I'm not sure how to build the predicate to return the expected result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `every` in your predicates, to specify that every key in your sequence must satisfies being the value of a `corresp` attribute, for a candidate `list` element.

The expression looks like: `every $v in $seq satisfies $v`, which returns true if the expression on the right-hand side of `satisfies` returns true for every value in `$seq`.  It returns false otherwise.

So in your example:

```
<lists>
  <list xml:id="first">
    <item corresp="a"/>
  </list>
  <list xml:id="second">
    <item corresp="a"/>
    <item corresp="b"/>
  </list>
  <list xml:id="third">
    <item corresp="b"/>
  </list>
  <list xml:id="third">
    <item corresp="c"/>
  </list>
  <list xml:id="forth">
    <item corresp="b"/>
    <item corresp="c"/>
  </list>
</lists>
/list[every $k in $keys satisfies item/@corresp = $k]
```

FYI, you also have `any`, that you use the same way as `every`, but which returns true if, you got it, the expression returns true for any item in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your request to

```
return $xml[item[@corresp="a"] and item[@corresp="b"]]
```

which will return the desired output

```
<list xml:id="second">
    <item corresp="a"/>
    <item corresp="b"/>
</list>
```

You have to make separate predicates for each `<item>` match.
I guess you were trying to simplify things too much, because you were selecting by an `OR` rather than an `AND`, because your predicate was checking if `item[@corresp...]` is contained in the set `("a","b")`.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be a hardcoded solution, but `("a","b")` could in fact be any number of combinations of parameters that need to be dynamically applied. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: The answer does not address how to dynamically construct the predicates based on  an unknown number of parameters to apply to `@corresp`. I should have indicated this element in the question. I might have just one parameter, or three or eight parameters to apply to `@corresp`.